# How to capture resize event floatingpane JavaScript from declarative method?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have seen the programmatic example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8azsz/2/

```
var fp;
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojo/on","dojox/layout/FloatingPane", "dijit/form/Button"], function(ready, parser, on, FloatingPane, Button) {
ready(function() {
    parser.parse();
    fp = new FloatingPane({
        title: "Test",
        resizable: true,
        dockable: false,
        style:"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;height:100px;visibility:hidden;",
        id: "fp"
        }, dojo.byId("fp"));
        fp.startup();
        on(fp._resizeHandle, "resize", function(e) {
           // Event handler
            console.log("test");
        });
    });
});
```

The question is, how do i do this when i am using a declarative method of creating the floatingpane?

Comment: I would guess data-dojo-attach-event could help you with that. Have a look at this Tutorial. https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/templated/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dojo declarative scripting example.
See https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declarative/
Specially section "Modifying Behavior"

You will need something like :

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/dijit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css">


<div id="floatingPane" data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/FloatingPane"
            data-dojo-props="title: 'Hello World!',resizable:true,dockable: false">
  <p>I am a floating pane. That makes me happy See browser console for the resize event.</p>

  <script type="dojo/aspect" data-dojo-advice="after" data-dojo-event="resize">
           console.log("resize is executed");
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Ben, when i use this code within my floating pane the chart that i have inside the floating pane does not show up and the resizing doesnt work either. Is there a way to make that script a function and call on the specific floating pane ID?

Comment: I understand. I am creating the floating pane decoratively, but need a programmatic function to capture the resize. The example i showed above does it all programmatic and i couldn't figure out how to do it in a combined method.

Comment: Well, give an id to you declarative floating pane then execute something like `on(dijit.byId("FLOATINGPANEID")._resizeHandle, "resize", function(e) { // Event handler console.log("test"); });`